# Cannot implicitly convert type to Func

Tags: c#, casting, func

I'm trying to write an asynchronous app to get values from (remote) library. And I stumbled on an action method giving the error "Cannot implicitly convert type to Func".

I tried various return types...

```
    private static void CallAsynch2()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            tasks.Add(Task<KeyValuePair<int, string>>.Factory.StartNew(GetValueAction(i)));

    }

    private static Func<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetValueAction(int i)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, i.ToString());
        //return ClassLibraryService.RandomValue.GetRandomValue(i);
    }
```

I expect it to return values to populate a dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Func and Cannot implicitly convert type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095121/func-and-cannot-implicitly-convert-type)

Comment: Not really. Here the confusion is between an object and a Func, whereas in the possible duplicate it is abound passing a Func, for which the argument has already been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This returns a `KeyValuePair`:

> ```
> return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, i.ToString());
> ```

You want to return a `Func`-tion of it:

```
return () => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, i.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Func is an anonymous method.
That means, that you give it zero or some values, and expect something in return.

In this line:

```
return new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, i.ToString());
```

you take an object of type KeyValuePair, and try to use it as an anonymous method.
This cannot work for various reasons, the why would blow this answer though.

In your case, you want an anonymous method, that takes zero arguments, and returns a KeyValuePair.
The correct code for that would be:

```
return () => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, i.ToString());
```

Note the "() =>" syntax.
This is a [lamda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) that gets implicitly converted to a Func.

Comment: You are right, it should be anonymous method.. below is working:

        private static void CallAsynch2()
        {
            Func<object, KeyValuePair<int, string>> action = (object obj) =>
            {
                int i = (int)obj;

                return new KeyValuePair<int,string>(i, i.ToString());
            };

            List<Task< KeyValuePair<int, string>>> tasks = new List<Task<KeyValuePair<int,string>>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
                tasks.Add(Task<KeyValuePair<int, string>>.Factory.StartNew(action,i));

        }